# One physical USB harddisk provides two ~2TB block devices, but I want one large 4TB device

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a vendor preformatted hard disk (Verbatim Store'n'Save USB 3.0 4TB). When connecting to my CentOS 6 server I can see 2 block devices /dev/sdd and /dev/sde with appropriate partitions, each of them about 2TB size. dmesg gives:

```
usb 4-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
usb 4-4: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0400
usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 4-4: Product: USB 3.0 Desktop HD
usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Verbatim
usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 30624C151155
usb 4-4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
scsi7 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usb-storage: device found at 3
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
usb-storage: device scan complete
scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MD04ACA400       FP2A PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MD04ACA400       FP2A PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 4294965248 512-byte logical blocks: (2.19 TB/1.99 TiB)
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 7:0:0:1: [sde] 3519071920 512-byte logical blocks: (1.80 TB/1.63 TiB)
sd 7:0:0:1: [sde] Write Protect is off
sd 7:0:0:1: [sde] Mode Sense: 1f 00 00 08
```

fdisk gives:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdd

Disk /dev/sdd: 2199.0 GB, 2199022206976 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267349 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1428089d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1      267350  2147480576    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I want to have only one device with 4TB size.
I tried to use parted to set the disk-label-typ to GPT but without success.

Comment: is it really completely unformatted?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

As physical sector size is 512 bytes, You can not have a single 4TB partition...

Comment: I think this is not true. The output of hdparam gives me 4096 bytes as you can see in the follwoing output:
hdparm -I /dev/sdd

/dev/sdd:

ATA device, with non-removable media
 Model Number:       TOSHIBA MD04ACA400                      
 Serial Number:      Z4KGK7POFSAA
 .....
 
 Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
 Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
 Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
 device size with M = 1024*1024:     3815447 MBytes
 device size with M = 1000*1000:     4000787 MBytes (4000 GB)
....

Comment: @Pulsar07: I do not have access to your disk. I just looked at the output of fdisk you put in the question. If you are sure your disk sector size is 4096 bytes, just delete the current partition table and rebuild another one having a single entry for the whole disk...